# Multicore resources in pure C

Tags: c, multicore

Would anyone know any pointers to information about multicore programming in C? I apologize if the question has been asked before, after a "bona fide" search, I couldn't find it. I'd be happy to delete if someone points me to it.

Comment: i would think that depends largely on the hardware architecture

Comment: Absolutely right, but I'm just talking about general examples and docs, say for intel (or amd) dual/quad cores. I'm hoping someone has already "decanted" the literature a bit, and know what's worth reading and what isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[C1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) is the unofficial name of the planned new standard for the C programming language.

> Multithreading support (_Thread_local
>   storage-class specifier, 
>   header including thread
>   creation/management functions, mutex,
>   condition variable and thread-specific
>   storage functionality, as well as the
>   _Atomic type qualifier and  for uninterruptible
>   object access)

Answer (score 2):

It is not included in the ANSI C standard, but if you are using Unix i would strongly suggest to take a look at Posix [Threads](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expecting upvotes... but I wanted to share this: [Multithreaded Algorithms Chapter](http://www.multicoreinfo.com/research/papers/whitepapers/MT-Algorithms-Chapter.pdf) of the Cormen book.

Answer (score 1):

i like to read http://www.drdobbs.com, http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/index.jhtml is specific to parallel stuff.

Sometimes its hard to find a specific topic there but its a very good resource IMO.  They also have RSS feeds for each topic.